# How to concatenate letter by letter from 2 different strings

Tags: c

I want to concatenate 2 different strings letter by letter. How can I do that?
For ex: `a = "hid", b = "jof"`
concatenated string should be **`"hjiodf"`**.

So far I have tried this much:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void concatenate2(char p[], char q[]) {
    int c = 0, d = 0;
    //Iterating through both strings
    while (p[c] != '\0' || q[d] != '\0' ) {
        //Increment first string and assign the value      
        c++;
        p[c] = q[d];
        //Increment second string and assign the value    
        d++;
        p[c] = q[d];
    }
}  //<<====== missing }

int main(void)
{
    char w[100], a[100];
    //input first string 
    printf("Input a string\n");
    gets(w);
    //input second string 
    printf("Input Second string\n");
    gets(a);
    //function call      
    concatenate2(w, a);
    //print result   
    printf("String obtained on concatenation is \"%s\"\n", w);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like c++. Which language did you mean?

Comment: ^^ maybe, but with that formatting, who can tell?

Comment: I don't see C++ here.

Comment: 'dint work' will just get you down and close votes.

Comment: http://ideone.com/D85tUS

Answer (score 1):

Your `concatenate2` doesn't really do concatenation, instead it does overwriting. Remember you have to expand `p` to have more spaces for characters from `q` - which you don't at the moment.

An elegant solution is already provided by chqrlie. This solution allows you to use your exact prototype for `concatenate2`. The only limitation of this solution is that the two strings must be of the same size.

Here I provide a different solution. The idea is to use an extra string for concatenation. It requires you to pass in an additional `concat` string. This solution allows concatenation of strings of different size, for example:

```
Input 1st string: aaaaaaaa
Input 2nd string: bb
String obtained on concatenation is "ababaaaaaa"
```

Refer to the complete code below (note I replaced your `gets` with `fgets` which is a much safer way for input string).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void concatenate2( const char p[], const char q[], char concat[] ) 
{
    size_t p_idx = 0, q_idx = 0;
    size_t concat_idx = 0;

    // Iterating through both strings.
    while( p[p_idx] != '\0' || q[q_idx] != '\0' )
    {
        if( '\0' != p[p_idx] )
        {
            concat[concat_idx++] = p[p_idx++];
        }

        if( '\0' != q[q_idx] )
        {
            concat[concat_idx++] = q[q_idx++];
        }
    }

    concat[concat_idx] = '\0';
}


int main(void)
{
    char w[100] = "", a[100] = "", concat[200] = "";

    // Input first string.
    printf( "Input 1st string: " );
    if( NULL == fgets( w, sizeof( w ), stdin ) ) 
    {
        perror( "Invalid input" );
        return -1;
    }
    w[strlen( w ) - 1] = '\0';

    // Input second string.
    printf("Input 2nd string: ");
    if( NULL == fgets( a, sizeof( a ), stdin ) ) 
    {
        perror( "Invalid input" );
        return -1;
    }
    a[strlen( a ) - 1] = '\0';

    // Concat the two strings.
    concatenate2( w, a, concat );

    // Print the result.
    printf( "String obtained on concatenation is \"%s\"\n", concat );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function does not null terminate the destination array.

Comment: it is much more reliable to set the null terminator in the `concatenate2` function than to rely on prior initialization.

Comment: @chqrlie I see, added `concat[concat_idx] = '\0';` to `concatenate2` - thanks!

Comment: correct.  This way, you leave `concat` uninitialized in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

function `concatenate2` does not work as written because it overwrites the destination buffer before its characters are used.

Modify it this way:

```
void concatenate2(char p[], const char q[]) {
    int i, len = strlen(p);
    p[len + len] = '\0';
    for (i = len; i-- > 0;) {
        p[i + i + 1] = q[i];
        p[i + i] = p[i];
    }
}
```

If the strings have different lengths, the specification is unclear as to how to combine the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since seems that you can't use C's strcat and I don't see that you have to use arrays, I recommend that you use pointers, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc/free

int concatenate (char *buffer, int buffsize, const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    int npos = 0;
    // concatenate s1 to buffer
    while (*s1 != '\0') {
        *buffer = *s1;
        buffer++;
        s1++;
        ++npos;
    }
    // concatenate s2 to buffer
    while (*s2 != '\0') {
        *buffer = *s2;
        buffer++;
        s2++;
        ++npos;
    }
    buffer = '\0';
    return npos;
}

int main () {
    const int buff_path = 64;
    char *buffer;
    int ret;
    buffer = (char*)malloc (sizeof(char)*buff_path);
    ret = concatenate (buffer, buff_path, "hello", " world");
    printf ("This is the string: [%s]\nstring len: %i\n", buffer, ret);
    free (buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your proposal does not meet the OP's goal.